# facet_wrap bar plot customization

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to remove the Y axis scales (marked by red solid line) of facet_wrap graph.
[image]

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=Specie, y=mean, fill=Treatment))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), color="black")+
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=0.2,position=position_dodge(0.9), 
                color="blue")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = number_format(accuracy = 0.01),
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1))
```

Comment: I don't know that you can do this easily with `ggplot2` alone, but you can use `patchwork` to combine two on the left with two on the right, making sure to "collect" legends (I think `plot_layout(guides="collect")` or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to set individual y axis scales for your facets using `ggh4x::faceted_pos_scales`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

left  <- scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.01))
right <- scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.01),
                            position = "right")

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Specie, y = mean, fill = Treatment)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(), color = "black")+
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.9), 
                color = "blue") +
  facetted_pos_scales(y = list(left, right, left, right))
```

[image]

---

**Data used - reverse engineered from plot and code in question**

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Specie = rep(rep(c("S. chacoense", "S. commersoni", 
                               "S. tuberosum 2x"), each = 2), 4),
                  Treatment = rep(c("CT", "HS"), 12),
                  variable = factor(rep(c("Pn", "Gs", "E", "WUE"), each = 6),
                                    c("Pn", "Gs", "E", "WUE")),
                  mean = c(7.5, 9, 8.5, 10, 8.5, 13, 0.19, 0.18, 0.25, 0.2,
                           0.25, 0.24, 2.8, 3.8, 3, 4.5, 3.8, 5.9,
                           3.1, 2.9, 3.5, 2.4, 2.4, 2.25),
                  sd = c(2.6, 2.7, 2.6, 2.5, 3, 1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.16, 0.1,
                         0.16, 0.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 2.5, 0.8, 1.8, 1.2,
                         1.8, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3))
```